# INDEX MATCH array formula returns #N/A if table has single row

Tags: excel

I am working with INDEX MATCH formula with multiple criteria in a Excel Table. My array formula looks like

```
{=INDEX(Table1,MATCH(1,(Table1[Column1]=value1)*(Table1[Column2]=value2), 0))}
```

The formula works fine if table has more than one row. The formula fails and returns `#N/A` when table has 1 row. Is there any workaround for table with single row?

**Edit:**

My Table is pulling data through database using power query. Hence number of rows are dynamic. 
Table is as follows

```
Column1  |  Column2  |  Column3
-------------------------------
value1   |  value2   |  value3
```

Comment: Did you notice, data is matching with 1st row as only one row?

Comment: You are matching data from 2 tables? If so, you confirmed that you have matching rows?

Comment: "The formula works fine if table has more than one row." are you referring to Table1 or Table2 ?

Comment: Provide examples of both tables.

Comment: I have written Table2[Column2] by mistake. It is Table1[Column2].